# Packaging ODBC driver - SQLalchemy for MS SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm using sqlalchemy in connection with pyodbc to connect to an MS SQL Server instance.

I prepare the connection string as below, and then pass that to sqlalchemy to create the engine:

```py
uri = f"mysql+pyodbc://{user_auth}@{hostname}/{dbname}?trusted_connection=yes&DRIVER=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
```

This works when I run it on my local machine, but I want to distribute this code (build an exe). As I understand it, the above snippet will only run on a machine that has the right driver installed. e.g. When I replace the ODBC+Driver+17 with ODBC+Driver+13 for example, I get an error because I don't have this driver installed. So I would anticipate a similar issue when I distribute this to users.

What is the best practice for dealing with this? Is there a way for me to package/install the driver on the target system? Do I need to catch this error and prompt the users to please go download the missing driver?

Comment: Aside... `{user_auth}`, SQL Logons with usernames and passwords, and `trusted_connection=yes`, Active Directory/Kerberos/Windows Logons with process tokens, are competing authentication methods. You should choose one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the callout - I didn't know that trusted_connection was specific to AD/Windows Auth, duly noted.